# how to programmatically enable Auto-start option for my app in Chinese devices?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

how to enable auto start option in my app without user influence? please help me

```
   public class BootUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       Intent i = new Intent(context, Splash_Screen.class);
       i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       context.startActivity(i);
   }
}
```

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" 
  />

 <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".BootUpReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: I want to auto start on bcz i don't get FCM notification when application is in killed or closed and when i on auto start manullay FCM notification work perfectly. what i am doing please help me

Comment: I guess you have a problem with your FCM implementation and you're trying to make a workaround. Why don't you open a question about how to fix the FCM?

Comment: My friend @Ricardo A no problem in FCM implementation bcz other device it works like charm but not work in Chinese device l.e Vivo,opp, etc.

Comment: You have to ask the user to enable auto-start your app, or get your app whitelisted by these Chinese Manufacturers (they enable auto-start for whitelisted app by default). Anything else is just an illusion. It will not work. That's the way it is with them!

Comment: okay thanks @Rahul Shukla

Comment: how to i do whitelisted my app by chinese manufacturers any idea? i have no idea about that